# Transformation hasn't been executed yet building android app with flutter in docker

Tags: android, docker, gradle, flutter

I'm trying to build android app with flutter inside https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android container.

I install flutter inside the container (flutter doctor says everything is ok), clone latest version of my code.

When I run 
`flutter build apk --debug`
I get

```
Resolving dependencies...                                           4.2s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Transformation hasn't been executed yet

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         2.9s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What's wrong? Looks like the container is intended for building android apps?

Comment: this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840761/gradle-transformation-hasnt-been-executed-yet

Comment: Could that be java issue? There is openjdk in container. Do I need to replace it with Oracle?